# C# Generic Inheritance workaround

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Example:

I'd like to have several specialized textboxes that derive from either TextBox or RichTextBox, which both derive from TextBoxBase:

```
class CommonFeatures<T> : T where T : TextBoxBase
{
  // lots of features common to the TextBox and RichTextBox cases, like
    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //using TextBoxBase properties/methods like SelectAll();  
    }
}
```

and then

```
class SpecializedTB : CommonFeatures<TextBox>
{
    // using properties/methods specific to TextBox
    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        ... base.OnTextChanged(e); 
    }
}
```

and

```
class SpecializedRTB : CommonFeatures<RichTextBox>
{
    // using methods/properties specific to RichTextBox
}
```

Unfortunately

```
class CommonFeatures<T> : T where T : TextBoxBase
```

doesn't compile ("Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter").

Is there a good solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: It should be class CommonFeatures<T> where T : TextBoxBase

Comment: @Tomas Voracek well that's the point, class CommonFeatures<T> : T where T : TextBoxBase because CommonFeatures needs to derive from a class which inherits TextBoxBase's methods/properties otherwise things like OnTextChanged don't exist. And if I inherit from TextBoxBase directly, how do I add the properties/methods from RichTextBox or TextBox later, without multiple inheritance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# generics don't support inheritance from a parameter type.

Do you really need `CommonFeatures` to derive from `TextBoxBase`?

A simple workaround may be to use aggregation instead of inheritance. So that you would have something like this:

```
public class CommonFeatures<T> where T : TextBoxBase
{
    private T innerTextBox;

    protected CommonFeatures<T>(T inner)
    {
        innerTextBox = inner;
        innerTextBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    public T InnerTextBox { get { return innerTextBox; } }

    protected virtual void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        ... do your stuff            
    }
}
```

Like @oxilumin says, extension methods may also be a great alternative if you don't really need `CommonFeatures` to be a `TextBoxBase`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that, I suppose you mean:

class SpecializedRTB : RichTextBox
{
 private CommonFeatures<RichTextBox> cf = new CommonFeatures<RichTextBox>(this);
 // SpecializedRTB's TextChanged event already caught.
}

How did I not think of that :)

Answer (score 1):

If your `CommonFeature` class has not an it's own condition - you can use extension methods for this.

```
public static class TextBoxBaseExtensions
{
    public static YourReturnType YourExtensionMethodName(this TextBoxBase textBoxBase, /*your parameters list*/)
    {
        // Method body.
    }
}
```

And then you can use this method in the same way with all real class-methods:

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.YourExtensionMethodName(/* your parameters list */);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that but does that allow the protected override mechanism?

I would have to add

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e) { ... base.ExtensionOnTextChanged(e); }

by hand in both classes?

Comment: @SemMike: No, with extension methods you have access only to public members of class.