# C# macro-style generics

Tags: c#, templates, generics, macros

I am looking for a way to have generics which only exist at compile time for the purpose of code reuse: not having to copy/paste classes and methods. Just text replacement basically, like macros, with some type checks. More like C++ templates.

Reason why I am asking:

Normal C# generics insist on always creating generic types at run-time (why??), which

1) not only creates unnecessary limitations (e.g. cannot inherit from a type parameter, which would be very useful),

2) but these run-time generic types are creating problems for me right now because .NET cannot serialize them, so when I insert them into a RichTextBox, many operations either fail or throw "Cannot serialize a generic type" exceptions. Everything was working with non-generic types but I wanted to make the code more general to add things so I added generics ( [C# Generic Inheritance workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090432/c-generic-inheritance-workaround)), and they are breaking everything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While C# doesn't have C++-style templates, you could try using [T4 (the Text Template Transformation Toolkit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to mimic them.

Your file would look something like:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    foreach (var T in new[]{"instantiate","for","these","types"})
    {
#>      

class FakeGeneric<#=T#>
{
    <#=T#> FakeGenericField;
}

<#  } #>
```

This would generate the types like this:

```
class FakeGenericinstantiate
{
    instantiate FakeGenericField;
}

class FakeGenericfor
{
    for FakeGenericField;
}

// etc
```

There's [a page on MSDN about using T4 to generate code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) like this.

Comment: Oh wow, seems like it's a new 2010 feature... it's both pretty and pretty ugly at the same time. :]

Answer (score 1):

They're called *templates* (not "macro-style generics") and they **do not exist** in C#.

Take a look at [D](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/) if you're interested; it has a lot of template metaprogramming capabilities, more (and IMO better than) C++ or C#.