# C++ style templates in C#, possible in any way?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, templates, generics

I want to have 2d vector classes for every primitive type.

Right now, to assure the best runtime performance and be able to use many utility functions, I need to have a separate class for every primitive (Vector2Int, Vector2Float, Vector2Long, etc).

It's just a lot of copy-pasting, and if I have to make a change I have to remember to do it in every class and in every utility function.

Is there anything that lets me write something like C++ templates (or is there any way I can create it)?

I created a little concept to show you how this would work:

```
// compile is a keyword I just invented for compile-time generics/templates

class Vector2<T> compile T : int, float, double, long, string
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }

    public T GetLength() 
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2));
    }
}

// during compilation, code will be automatically generated
// as if someone manually replaced T with the types specified after "compile T : "
/*
    VALID EXAMPLE (no compilation errors):

    autogenerated class Vector2<int>
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public int GetLength() 
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2));
        }
    }



    UNVALID EXAMPLE (build failed, compilation errors):

    autogenerated class Vector2<string>
    {
        public string { get; set; } // ok
        public string { get; set; } // ok

        public string GetLength() 
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2)); // error! string cannot be used with Math.Pow()
                                             // and Math.Sqrt doesn't accept string type
        }
    }
*/
```

Is there some clever way to implement this, or is this completely impossible?

---

Sorry for not being very clear, but let me explain what the problem is.

Consider using normal C# generics. The GetLength() method wouldn't compile, because all the types I want to use (int, float, double, long) would require to share an interface which Math.Pow() should accept as a parameter.

Literally substituting the "T" token with the type names would solve this problem, increase flexibility, reach hand-written code performance and speed up development.

---

I made my own template generator, which generates C# code by writing C# code :) 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz868MuVvTY

Comment: Keep in mind `X ^ 2` doesn't mean *X to the power of 2*. It means *X bitwise xored with 2*. As for the question, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Why can't you just use regular generics? Unlike Java generics, they do *not* box values types.

Comment: @chris whoops, gonna fix the example code now. The problem is that C# generics are not as flexible as a compile-time template (like C++). If I had a Vector<T> class I wouldn't be able to have a GetLength() method unless all the primitive types I was interested in shared an interface.

With compile-time templates, the compiler literally replaces the token "T" with a type. Then it compiles the newly generated class, and in case of errors the build fails. This allows anything, from the sum of primitive types to having custom types with overloaded operators, and being free from interface-sharing.

Comment: @delnan the GetLength() method wouldn't work with normal generics. All the types need to share a interface. Also, the vector example is only one of the many situations where compile-time templates would come in handy. 

Literally replacing the "T" token with the type name would allow the developer much more flexibility, and performance equal to hand-written code.

Comment: C# generics are "compile time" templates as well, there is no difference in that regard.  The difference is the semantics.  C++ templates are little more than text replacement mechanisms, which makes them more powerful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# macro-style generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092861/c-sharp-macro-style-generics)

Comment: @EdS. but the "compile time" for C# generics is "just in time" compile time, not csc.exe compile time.

Comment: @phoog: Yes it is csc.exe compile time. The rules of generics are enforced by the C# compiler and the bytecode generated.  I don't understand the distinction. The only difference is that the rules differ between C++ templates and C# generics.

Comment: @EdS. If we define `Processor<T>` and use it with T = int, byte, and double, the csc compiler will create one type (`Processor<T>`), while the jit compiler will create three (`Processor<int>`, `Processor<byte>`, and `Processor<double>`).  If we define templating as the substitution of type arguments to create many types, that happens in the JIT compiler, not in csc.exe.

Comment: @phoog: Except the problem here is how to accomplish something like `T Add<T>(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }`, which you can't, because generics don't allow for it with basic types like `int`, `double`, etc., and your code won't compile.  What the jit compiler would do with it is irrelevant; you'll never make it to the jit compiler.  I know what you're getting at, I just don't see how it is relevant in this discussion.

Comment: @EdS. Exactly.  And that's why the difference in "compile time" is significant.  If the type substitution were done by csc, it could handle things like `T Add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }`, rejecting it only if the program actually uses a type argument that doesn't have a + operator.

Comment: @phoog: Well... I think we're arguing semantics here, but C# is simply enforcing the rules of generics per the language specification.  However, you bring up an interesting point, one I was unaware of.  Time to do some reading...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, generics in C# are very different than templates in C++.  In order to accomplish this, a shared interface (such as `IArithmetic`) would have to exist [(which has been highly requested, but not implemented)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94264/arithmetic-types-like-int-double-decimal-should-implement-iarithmetic-t&ei=RwxNULCfBI7biwKp5oG4Cw&usg=AFQjCNFVLpZ0XC4UJCrpFedoj_kmmsDv2Q&sig2=joH648rIIBzLQIBxTBKTxw)* for the different types, and this doesn't in the framework now.

This can be done via code generation and [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), however, but it requires generating the code for each type based off a shared "template".

*Note: The connect request appears to be blocked, at least temporarily.

Comment: The fact that an interface such as IArithmetic doesn't exist is the problem here. But I can also imagine that compile-time templates would be very useful to create flexible and "hand-written performance" code in many situations.

I will look into T4 templates, I hope they can help.

Comment: @Vee You'll find this very frustrating - many people have been annoyed at the difficulty involved in making this work.  Every option is a bit of a hack. :(

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into it right now, and the complexity isn't promising. I just wish there was a way to do what I described in the first post. 

My only idea is creating an application which has to be ran before building the solution. The application generates .cs files, somehow attaches them to the solution, and somehow tells Visual Studio to compile the solution with those newly generated files.

Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: @Vee That's effectively what T4 does.  I'd learn to use it if you really need/want this, as it's very useful, once you learn it.

Comment: Not happy with the complexity of T4, I made a template generator (that automatically adds generated files to a .csproj: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz868MuVvTY

Comment: T4 combined with Roslyn gives all power of templates into C#. I used such approach to read C# classes and generate wrappers with exception handling wrapping applied. Will suite math classes either if to define psuedo number `struct Numeric` and generate concretes out of this. I used this approach in matrixextensions.codeplex.com

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda Yes, and I mentioned that in my answer - but T4 is really not "part of" C# - it's a completely separate toolset to learn (though not really C# specific)

Comment: It embedded info each IDE for C# (SD, MonoDevelop, VS), not sure if somebody develops without IDE, but from this perspective this is "part of C#". Now parser libs are "part of C#". Learning T4 toolset is as hard as learn C++ template embedded into C++ (which are quite separated of old school C++ either).

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions to this problem:

1. Make an abstract class or interface calculator[t] and implement it for the types you care about. Pass an instance of the calculator to your vector classes so they can use it to do mathematical operations.
2. Using expression trees, you can actually create a static class calculator[t] that has methods like add, pow, etc. in the static constructor, you can compile dynamic expressions and the have the static methods call these compiled lambdas. With this approach, you don't have to implement the calculator for each type or pass it around (since its static).

For example:

```
public static class Calculator<T> {

   public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Add;
   public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Pow;

   static Calculator() {
       var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
       var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
       var addLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Add(p1, p2), p1, p2);
       Add = addLambda.Compile();

       // looks like the only Pow method on Math works for doubles
       var powMethod = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Pow", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
       var powLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(
           Expression.Convert(
               Expression.Call(
                   powMethod,
                   Expression.Convert(p1, typeof(double)),
                   Expression.Convert(p2, typeof(double)),
               ),
               typeof(T)
           ),
           p1,
           p2
       );
       Pow = powLambda.Compile();
   }
}

// and then in your class

T a, b;
var sum = Calculator<T>.Add(a, b);
var pow = Calculator<T>.Pow(a, b);
```